# Poisson distribution with a constant term

Tags: generalized-linear-model, poisson-regression, discrete-data

I have a set of data constituted by two columns: $Y$ with non-negative discrete values, depending on a time $t$.

I make the hypothesis that $Y$ is a Poisson distribution, with:

$$\operatorname {E} (Y\mid t )=e^{At + B} + C $$

When $C=0$ this is a well known generalised linear model, but how can find a good fit for data with an unknown value of $C$ ?

Comment: @FP0's answer seems about right. If you want to know **how** to do it, it's more of a Stack Overflow question, but `bbmle::mle2` should work: `mle2(y ~ exp(a*t +b) + exp(logC), data = your_data, start = list(a=0, b=1, c = 0))` (you do need sensible starting values, and things will get a little wonky in the limit where $C \to 0$ (because $\log(C) \to -\infty$))

Comment: @Ben At the risk of repeating part of another comment, the model is not necessarily restricted to positive $C.$  Your points about needing good starting values are good.

Comment: True. You could let $C$ be unconstrained, and the default optimizer (Nelder-Mead) should probably be able to handle some NA values, but the problem could get a bit ugly ...

Comment: @Ben Surprisingly, it doesn't get ugly, at least not with many datasets I have generated (which cover many different behaviors).  The only real problems I encountered concerned finding a decent starting value for the parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to model your observations with $Y\lvert t \sim \text{Pois}\left(\lambda\left(t\right)\right)$ with $\lambda\left(t\right)=e^{At+B}+C$, then you will have:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\left(Y=k\lvert t\right)&=e^{-\lambda(t)}\frac{\lambda(t)^k}{k!}\\
&=e^{-\left(e^{At+B}+C\right)}\frac{\left(e^{At+B}+C\right)^k}{k!}
\end{align}

If you have a sample of $n$ independent values $\{t_i, y_i\}, i=1,...,n$, you can use the equation above to define the log-likelihood of your sample as a function of your parameters $A,B,C$. Then, you can use an optimiser in order to find the parameters maximising the log-likelihood function. I would suggest using a parameter $C\prime=\ln(C)$ instead of $C$ directly in order to make sure that $C$ will be positive, in order to get $\lambda(t)>0$ $\forall t>0$.

Comment: (1) The model is possible even with negative $C,$ depending on the range of the $t_i.$ (2) Yes, this is a good approach.  What is problematic is unless the data are very numerous or the plot is very strongly curved and approaches its horizontal asymptote, the hessian will be highly ill conditioned: that is, this model can be nearly non-identifiable.  This also implies good starting values for the estimate may be needed. Thus, it's plausible a better solution to the underlying statistical problem can be found by persuading the OP to develop a different model if possible.

Comment: (1) Could you please explain why it is possible with $C<0$? It could theoretically allow $\lambda$ to become negative for some values of $A,B,t$, right? How could we handle this without modifying the definition of $\lambda$?
(2) Your remarks and suggestions are useful. Do you have tricks you could share which could help guessing good starting values for the optimisation?

Comment: The model cannot be extended infinitely far on the $t$ axis, but nobody extrapolates any model like that anyway.  All you need is that $\exp(At_i+B)+C\ge 0$ for all $i.$  It really does work--I created data according to such models and successfully fit them when the question was posted.

Comment: OK thanks. As long as there is some procedure in the optimisation to avoid that $\lambda$ becomes negative when the values of $A,B,C$ are changed, then it should be OK indeed.

Comment: @whuber What i mainly need, is extrapolating the limit for $t\rightarrow \infty$. I know this is a bad use of any statistical method, but I need a best guess for this value

Comment: You don't need to characterize that as extrapolating.  When the estimate of $A$ is positive, the value diverges; when it is negative, its asymptote is the estimate of $C.$ Thus, you are concerned with the precision and accuracy of those two estimates.  They will be poor unless you have data *both* for sufficiently large and small $t.$ So, it will be important to compute the standard errors of those estimates (which can be done in the usual way with the Maximum Likelihood apparatus).